# You've Probably Seen Me Naked

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, knowledge

> As an alphabet aficionado, I can make you laugh long into the night.
>   As a make of Japanese vehicle, I can keep your surroundings clean and beautiful.
>   As an execution apparatus, I make you laugh despite not maturing.
>   As a mixed-up romance, I lead tens of millions.
>   As a gardening tool, I provide weekend evening entertainment and provide guidelines for proposing.
>   As a reddish-brown meadow, I dazzle you with tricks.
>   As a fighting knife, I make popular music and navigate a maze.
>   As a speech-impaired aquatic athlete, I am your friend.
>   As a renter, I am your doctor.

***Who am I?***

Comment: Do they all give a single word? Or every sentence give single words and all those words constitutes to give a MEGA-single word?

Comment: @manshu Now why would I give extra clues only 10 minutes after the puzzle was posted?   :)

Comment: -1 for click bait

Comment: @CaptainCodeman What? Because it has the word 'naked'? Look at the top voted riddles on this site, and you'll see that this one isn't out of the ordinary.

Comment: @CaptainCodeman +1 for clickbait. Clickbait answers always cheer me up.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

This is a compilation of many previous answers and adding of my own. Most of the credit to [Paul Evans](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/28202/4421), [Sleafar](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/28203/4421), [charfellow](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/28205/4421), and [question_asker](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/28204/4421) (in no particular order).

The answer is:

> **David**

You've probably seen me naked.

> The **[Statue of David](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_(Michelangelo))** is a famous statue of King David in the nude.  (from charfellow)

As an alphabet aficionado, I can make you laugh long into the night.

> **[David Letterman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Letterman)**, comedian and former late-show talk host.  A *letter man* is an alphabet aficionado.  (from question_asker)

As a make of Japanese vehicle, I can keep your surroundings clean and beautiful.

> **[David Suzuki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Suzuki)**, environmental activist.  [Suzuki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suzuki) is a make of vehicle from Japan.  (from question_asker)

As an execution apparatus, I make you laugh despite not maturing.

> **[David Cross](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Cross)**, comedian and actor on [Arrested Development](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrested_Development_(TV_series)).  A *cross* is an ancient method of execution, and *not maturing* = *arrested development*.

As a mixed-up romance, I lead tens of millions.

> **[David Cameron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Cameron)**, prime minister of the UK.  *Cameron* is an anagram of *romance*.  (from Paul Evans)

As a gardening tool, I provide weekend evening entertainment and provide guidelines for proposing.

> **[David Spade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Spade)**, a comedian on [Saturday Night Live](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturday_Night_Live) and an actor in [Rules of Engagement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rules_of_Engagement_(TV_series)).
>  *weekend evening entertainment* = *Saturday Night Live*
>  *guidelines for proposing* = *rules of engagement*.

As a reddish-brown meadow, I dazzle you with tricks.

> **[David Copperfield](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Copperfield_(illusionist))**, illusionist.  A *reddish-brown meadow* is a *copper field*.  (from question_asker)

As a fighting knife, I make popular music and navigate a maze.

> **[David Bowie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Bowie)**, acclaimed singer, and actor in the movie *[Labyrinth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Labyrinth_(film))*. A *[Bowie knife](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bowie_knife)* is a popular knife originally made for fighting, and a *maze* is a *labyrinth*. (from  Sleafar)

As a speech-impaired aquatic athlete, I am your friend.

> **[David Schwimmer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Schwimmer)**, actor on the TV show *[Friends](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friends)*. An *aquatic athlete* is a *swimmer*, which might be pronounced, "*schwimmer*" by someone with a speech impairment. (from charfellow)

As a renter, I am your doctor.

> **[David Tennant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Tennant)**, actor on the TV show *[Doctor Who](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_Who)*.  A *renter* is a *tenant*, and he plays the role of the *doctor*. (from charfellow)

Comment: "weekend evening entertainment" = Saturday Night Live

Comment: And if your correction from Lynch is correct, then "Arrested Development" fits the rest of the clue.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain Looks like [speaking German](http://dict.tu-chemnitz.de/dings.cgi?query=schwimmer&service=deen) is considered a speech impediment nowadays. ;)

Comment: @Sleafar I don't speak German, or I might have used that in the clue.  But from an English perspective, the clue still makes sense.

Comment: It should be converted into community wiki now.. :)

Comment: @Sleafar Except that in German it's pronounced "shvimmer", with a *v* sound, not a *w* sound.

Answer (score 20):

As a mixed-up romance, I lead tens of millions.

> Possibly David **Cameron** (anagram of *romance*) who lead tens of millions as the Prime Minister of the UK?

As a gardening tool, I provide weekend evening entertainment and provide guidelines for proposals.

> David Spade comedian and star of Rules of Engagement

Comment: Aah, another anagram of `romance`.

Comment: Who you've probably seen naked?

Comment: @user1717828 hahaha, we all can as [Iggle Piggle](http://i.huffpost.com/gen/569749/images/r-DAVID-CAMERON-IGGLE-PIGGLE-large570.jpg)!

Answer (score 19):

To supplement others' answers, many have seen

> The statue of David

naked

And

> David Schwimmer played Ross on Friends

and

> David Tennant plays the Doctor

Answer (score 18):

As a fighting knife, I make popular music and navigate a maze.

> There is a [Bowie knife](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bowie_knife), and David Bowie is a singer and was in the movie [Labyrinth](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Labyrinth_(film)).

Answer (score 17):

A reddish-brown meadow who dazzles with tricks could be

> David Copperfield

The alphabet aficionado who makes you laugh into the night is

> David Letterman

The Japanese vehicle/beautiful surroundings is

> David Suzuki