# Quite the talented insects, aren't we?

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, knowledge

> As I stab through your armor, I throw balls. 
>   As a foot traveler, you can watch me drive cars. 
>   As a silver fish, I transform into an ant. 
>   As an early teacher, I am not actually one of what I'm named. 
>   As a reborn person, I have quite the cool hand. 
>   As an alien, my voice isn't actually an alien. 
>   As myself alone, I'm humble and small.

***Who am I?***

Comment: Yes heavily inspired from: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/28201/youve-probably-seen-me-naked

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are

> Paul

Almost the same gimmick as the other, with a few oddballs in there too:

Title: Quite the talented insects, aren't we?

> Paul McCartney - Member of the **Beatles**
> Paul **Insect** - A street artist

As I stab through your armor, I throw balls.

> (MOehm) Paul **Pierce** - basketball player

As a foot traveler, you can watch me drive cars.

> Paul **Walker** - actor in fast and furious

As a silver fish, I transform into an ant.

> Paul **Rudd** - Ant-man actor

As an early teacher, I am not actually one of what I'm named.

> Paul the Apostle - He was an early teacher and @lplant pointed out he isn't actually one of the 12 apostles.

As a reborn person, I have quite the cool hand.

> Paul **Newman** - Actor of 'Cool hand luke'

As an alien, my voice isn't actually an alien.

> Paul - the film about an alien who has a voiceover that isn't alien.

As myself alone, I'm humble and small.

> Paul - the name means small or humble (thanks @lplant)

Comment: The first one is Pierce.  And the alien is Gray.

Comment: As an early teacher, I am not actually one of what I'm named: Paul the Apostle wasn't actually one of the 12 apostles but taught the gospel in the 1st century.

Comment: As myself alone, I'm humble and small: According to Wikipedia the name Paul means "Small"; "humble"; "scarce"; "rare"

Comment: @lPlant thanks... I was looking at paul the apostle but couldn't find anything.. Didn't know he wasn't actually an apostle.